# Terror behind the wheel

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of *"terror behind the wheel"* in the following context?

> As I write these words, this book hasn't yet gone to press, and
>   already there are so many people working to support it. Sheryl Johnson, who is a
>   great publicist and a **terror behind the wheel**. Buzz Yancey, who tried to create, well, buzz...

(taken from Acknowledgements of "A Dog's Purpose" by W.Bruce Cameron)

Comment: I would think *very competitive*, like a race car driver.

Comment: @Bread But it can also mean that he is a very bad driver, isn't it? I haven't found no reference for your positive meaning.

Comment: @RubioRic - yes, all hits refer  either to bad drivers or to terrorist attacks.  We probably need more context. https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&ei=BdkoW9GwDIXKgAak96CQCA&q=terror+behind+the+wheel&oq=&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.1.1.41l3.0.0..509088...0....0.0.......0....1.......3.84y/4P6E%2Bp0%3D

Comment: @RubioRic I agree with you. Personally, when I hear "terror behind the wheel", I think about a terrorist attack (unfortunately).

Comment: @user110518 I've added more context. Please have a look.

Comment: @RubioRic ~ Yes, a very bad driver was my first thought as well -- until I applied context to it. A little logic 101 goes a long way toward improving understanding or comprehension with any type of communication. Improved communication = improved interpersonal skills.  https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=communication+and+interpersonal+skills&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart

Comment: Well, we are not talking about a terrorist attack, that's for sure. She's just a very bad driver.

Comment: @RubioRic but it's strange to mention this in acknowledgements... He is thanking them all for their great contribution...

Comment: But it may be an internal joke between the writer and her publicist. I don't agree with @Bread and I don't get the point in his link.

Comment: Yes I agree, it is a joke between the writer and the publicist, also probably to create an effect of contrast between,: you are a great publicist .....but a bad driver ( said with respect and affection probably). Whatever the case, terror behind  the wheel here  means “bad driver”.

Comment: @RubioRic ~ an "internal joke" would be at least a little bit rude, in addition to being somewhat deceptive -- and would require a great logical leap to 'get it'. Not saying it doesn't occur, but it would be *ambiguous* which is something great communicators and sales reps usually should try to avoid.

Comment: @Bread Notice that you're the only one maintaining that. Maybe we missed that day in Logic 101 ;-P

Comment: @user110518 So you're telling us that Sheryl Johnson is a bad driver? If that's true, I would judge the reviewer as someone terribly crass.

Comment: @RubioRic ~ *you're the only one maintaining that*... Ah yes, I see your logic now. ;)

Comment: @Bread I'm not using logic and I don't know who is Sheryl Johnson. I've read a lot of acknowledment pages and it seems to me the right option here. Just a joke. I may be wrong but only the author got the right explanation.

Comment: I wonder why the question is considered to be bad by some users. Because it stirred up some emotion? Or because the phrase in question may be interpreted in a few ways? The site is called "English Language and Usage". I know all this off-topic stuff but isn't it English in use?

Comment: @RubioRic I certainly would never read a book by any author who would make such a rude "joke" against his female publicist in his acknowledgements. But then as I said in the beginning, I would have been inclined to take the phrase *metaphorically* (giving him the benefit of the doubt), rather than literally (which to me would be an indication of lousy writing skill). This whole exchange has been mildly surprising. I will just add it to the long list of books I'm not interested in reading, and settle for that. It's too bad the parties in question aren't present to defend themselves.

Comment: @Bread "William Bruce Cameron (born 1960 in Petoskey, Michigan) is an American author, columnist, and humorist." (Wikipedia). I think for humorists normal rules don't apply for acknowledgements. This book apparently was quite a success, so don't let a dubious in-joke ruin your literary experiences...

Comment: @Brad I see your point and I appreciate your point of view. I will just note that the book is amazing! It's really heartwarming and insightful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would mean "driving like a maniac":

This is from an article headlined *BOBBI KRISTINA'S BF
ARRESTED
Terror Behind the Wheel*:
"Bobbi Kristina's boyfriend Nick Gordon was arrested for driving like a maniac last night ... hours after Whitney Houston's daughter totaled a Chevy Camaro in a frightening wreck of her own."

Another article sports the headline: *MIRANDA COSGROVE: TRUSTED MOTORIST OR TERROR BEHIND THE WHEEL?*, so a terror behind a wheel is definitely not a trusted motorist or careful driver.

On Yahoo Answers, the question "[Are you a good driver?](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20170706052143AAu3FsY)" elicits one answer "Well no..I am a terror behind the wheel..nobody lets me drive..it boggles my mind.."

EDIT: I have found no mention of competitive driving. The sequence is also occasionally used in relation with terrorist attacks, but not as a noun phrase like this. Instead you will find something along the lines of *a ride of terror behind the wheel*, where *terror* is not the head of the phrase.

Comment: Why would the author mention that his publicist drives like a maniac in the acknowledgements section of his book?

Comment: It could be a tongue-in-cheek comment. She's a great publicist, but a terrible driver.

Comment: Well, I think you are right. It seems to be the only possible explanation. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: This is a literal interpretation of what must have been intended as a very colorful metaphor. There is absolutely no context for a publisher's driving skill, in a book review. It would have been so off-topic and unprofessional. To say that it *could* have a literal meaning in that particular context, is baseless and unfounded.

Comment: @Bread perhaps...

Comment: @Bread It's in the **acknowledgements.** You'll often find tongue-in-cheek comments in there. Like the following pun on Buzz' name. I agree that it would be out of place in a book review.

Comment: In British English, to call someone 'a terror' at something can just mean 'formidably capable or accomplished', any literal terror being felt by rivals, opponents, etc. A terror behind the wheel could mean a very skilled driver. The context would make this clear. My son is poor at the piano, so-so at the violin, but he's a terror with a saxophone!